# Making server lead server in Appfabric cache

Tags: appfabric

When you create an appfabric cluster the first server becomes the lead server.

Any servers that you then add to an existing cache are not lead servers.

How do you make a server a lead server? Is it just editing the clusterconfig.xml, or can it be done from the menu? Does anything need to be restarted after the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

export-cacheconfig, edit the config, stop-cachecluster, import-cacheconfig, start-cachecluster.